# Wikimedia Commons API query to get count of sub categories and photos in a category

Tags: categories, mediawiki-api, wikimedia-commons

I want to query a Wikimedia Commons category and get the count of sub categories and photos in a category.
For example when you look at the web page "[Category:Collections of the Brooklyn Museum](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Collections_of_the_Brooklyn_Museum)" in Wikimedia Commons, you get the list of subcategories.

One of the subcategories

> European art in the Brooklyn Museum‎ (7 C, 301 F)

has the numbers `7 C` and `301 F`  which means this has **7 categories** and **301 images**.

How do I query the Wikimedia Commons to get this category and image count information of subcategories?

I tried the following queries

http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmlimit=100&cmtitle=Category:Collections%20of%20the%20Brooklyn%20Museum

which gives me the category members of the category.

I can do an action render query which produces  the html representation from which I can  scrape the `7 C` and `301 F` count information.

What query can I use to get this count information without the html scraping?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`prop=categoryinfo`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categoryinfo) for this.

For example, the query:

> http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=categoryinfo&titles=Category:Collections%20of%20the%20Brooklyn%20Museum

returns:

```
<api>
  <query>
    <pages>
      <page pageid="21253813" ns="14" title="Category:Collections of the Brooklyn Museum">
        <categoryinfo size="105" pages="0" files="88" subcats="17" />
      </page>
    </pages>
  </query>
</api>
```